# Is there some feature in Visual Studio Team Services that can notify automatically when something has changed in files you monitor?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

Is there some feature in Visual Studio Team Services (TFS) that can notify automatically when something has changed in files you work with?

Lets say I have client-side angular app that uses client-server object models mappings to communicate with server-side code. If something is changed in C# models, on a client-side there is no way to know that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define Checkin alerts directly in the TFS configuration. These alert notifications are then sent out by mail.

For example you can set an alert if someone (perhaps other than yourself) does a checkin of specific files or in a specific directory. The possible criteria of the alert can be formulated in a pretty sophisticated way.

The alerts themselves can be made visible just for you or for all team members.

You can read more about the configuration of the alerts [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications).